# Is the correlation coefficient better than we think?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

In order to measure precisely the influence of one variable $Y$ over $X$ I wanted to use the mutual information because so far I believed that correlation coefficient (Pearson) was only limited to linear relation.

But I realized that even in non-linear cases it gives good results.

**Example in Matlab:**

$X$ is a uniform random variable and $I$ is the range of $X$

$Y=X^{2},I=[0,100]: \rho=0.96$

$Y=\sqrt{X} ,I=[0,100]: \rho=0.94$

$Y=exp(X),I=[0,10]: \rho=0.70$

$Y=log(X),I=[0,100]: \rho=0.84$

Why the correlation is quite high in all those non-linear cases? I am beginning to think that correlation is only weak when the monotony of $X$ and $Y$ is not the same. Otherwise it is not so bad.

Do some people have a point of view on this?

Comment: What is the meaning of $I=[0,100]$? For which values of $X$ did you calculate the correlation coefficient?

Comment: "when the mononty is changing": I imagine that you want to make  some point about monotonicity, or the lack of it, but I didn't feel confident at identifying exactly what you mean, so I left that unedited. Regardless of what you meant. it is easy to manufacture, or indeed find, cases with nonlinear and non-monotonic relationships where correlation is exactly or practically zero.

Comment: I is the range where $X$ takes its values.
@NickCox I mean I feel like when the monotony of $X$ is following the monotony of $Y$ we often find a high correlation coefficient regardless the type of relation (linear or non linear)

Comment: Sorry, but what you mean is completely unclear to me. It's the relation between the variables we are looking at. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function What precisely do you mean by the "monotony" of an individual variable?

Comment: No it's my fault sorry. I mean in all example I gave $Y$ is a strictly increasing function of $X$ so when you make a scatter plot of $(X,Y)$ you see that the monotony is not changing.

If I take $X$ in $[-100;100]$ and $Y=X.^{2}$ then $corr(X,Y)=0$ because (in part) $Y$ is not a monotonic function of $X$ whereas in my examples it is...

Uh. I hope I'm clearer now...

Comment: "monotony" is a standard English word but it does not, so far as I know, have the mathematical meaning you seem to think it has. Monotony changing is just a matter of not being monotonic, or of being non-monotonic. I don't think this question is getting clearer or more helpful to anyone else. If the point is that monotonic nonlinear relationships can be associated with high (Pearson) correlation, a short answer is Indeed; and a slightly longer answer is that your teachers or textbooks were at fault if they didn't emphasise that.

Comment: The correlation coefficient may be better than you think. It's not better than I think.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of monotonic examples in R (but very similar code works in Matlab):

```
> x=(1:100)
> y=exp(x)
> z=log(x)
> cor(z,y,method="kendall")
[1] 1
> cor(z,y,method="spearman")
[1] 1
> cor(z,y)
[1] 0.1549211
```

That's pretty low!

---

It's quite possible to make it much lower:

```
> cor(xxx,yyy,method="spearman")
[1] 1
> cor(xxx,yyy,method="kendall")
[1] 1
> cor(xxx,yyy)
[1] 0.010647
```

and in fact that very low Pearson correlation is caused by only a single outlier in x and a single outlier in y:

```
> cor(xxx[2:99],yyy[2:99])
[1] 1
```

So even when 98% of the points lie on a perfectly straight line, *and* the relationship is perfectly monotonic, the Pearson correlation can still be really close to zero.

---

---

In the case where $x$ is restricted to take the values 1, 2, ..., 100, the correlation can still be very low. Here's an example:

```
 cor(1:100,exp(1:100))
[1] 0.252032
```

I'm not sure how you got 0.7 - perhaps I misunderstood. I have another example with equispaced $x$ that is about 0.175.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand.  In your first code you compute $corr(exp(X),log(X))$ I agree with the low coefficient. But it's not the example I was taking.

In your last examples, I don't know what is 'xxx' and correlation is sensible to outliers, I agree. But my question was: why in the example of non linear cases I gave (without outliers) Pearson correlation is high?

Comment: If you limit $x$ to be equispaced (was that the intent?), then the minimum correlation is higher (but still a good deal lower than in your examples; I've included one at about 0.25. but it's possible to get quite a bit smaller than that). I didn't tell you the content of the second set of variables deliberately but only a general sense of how to obtain them - sometimes it's fun to discover on ones own.

Answer (score 1):

The more a function deviates from linearity, the smaller the correlation coefficient is.

---

Try this one:

```
> cor(1:100,factorial(1:100))
[1] 0.1740601
```

The `factorial` function is $f(x)=x!=\Gamma(x+1)$, monotonically increasing $\forall\space x\in\mathbb{N}$